# Компиляция через gulp-pug

Tags: html, gulp, frontend, сборка, pug

Есть несколько pug-шаблонов полей. В шаблонах прописаны ${name}. Есть объект со свойством name.

Хочу брать шаблоны и подставлять в переменные название полей и прочие атрибуты. 
Использую gulp и **gulp-pug**. Таск компилирует шаблоны, include работает отлично. А вот как сделать подстановку переменных?

Таск совершенно базовый:

```
gulp.task('pug', function () {
  return gulp.src(path.src.pug)
    .pipe(pug({pretty: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html));
});
```

https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html  тут описано, но не пойму где этот код должен быть расположен. И может быть именно для gulp-pug все иначе?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у Вас есть два pug-файла:
./layout/base.pug
./index.pug

В первом из них Вы прописываете:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    block page-title
    if title
      title #{name}
    - var name = 'Vasya'
```

Второй (index.pug) наследуете от этого файла base.pug следующим образом:

```
extends layout/base
block page-title
  - var name = "Petya"
```

Таким образом после обработки gulp-pug Вы получите html, 
title которого будет иметь значение 'Petya'.
А если Вы измените в index.pug значение переменной name на пустую строку, то Вы получите после сборки html,
title которого будет иметь значение 'Vasya'.
Как то так...